# ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table when using GORM

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

These are the tables in my database

```
CREATE TABLE vehicles
(
    id          VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
    make        VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    model       VARCHAR NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE collisions
(
    id            VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
    longitude     FLOAT NOT NULL,
    latitude      FLOAT NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE vehicle_collisions
(   
    vehicle_id    VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    collision_id  VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (vehicle_id, collision_id)
)
```

So i need to find list of vehicles with a particular collision_id. I am using gorm .

I tried to implement it in a way

```golang
    var vehicles []entities.Vehicles
    err := r.db.Joins("JOIN vehicles as vh on vh.id=vehicle_collisions.vehicle_id").Where("vehicle_collisions.collision_id=?",
        id).Find(&vehicles).Error
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
```

But it is throwing me error

```
 ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "vehicle_collisions" (SQLSTATE 42P01)
```

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: The `vehicles` is of type `[]entities.Vehicles` which presumably corresponds to the `vehicles` table. That means that if you pass `vehicles` to `Find` it will generate a `SELECT * FROM vehicles` adding a join to that like `JOIN vehicles ...` doesn't make sense, does it? It's also the reason why it complains that there is no `FROM clause` for `vehicle_collisions `. So just flip the tables in the JOIN clause and you should be good to go: https://go.dev/play/p/-Tv71Setmbl

Comment: Thank you @mkopriva for pointing at my mistake exactly but now it is panicing at `Find(&vehicles).Error` with the message ` panic serving [::1]:54547: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Field on slice Value` .

Comment: Can you show how the type of `entities.Vehicles` is defined? Is it a struct? Or is it a slice? Add the declaration to the question.

Comment: Never mind that was a mistake where i defined array and was creating array of array fixed it . Again Thank you so much for helping. One last thing if you can share some book or reference to learn Go for new people like me in golang.

Comment: I haven't read any Go book, only the official [language spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec), the [Effective Go](https://go.dev/doc/effective_go) guide, and the official [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/) of any package that I need to use. The one book I *heard* is good is [this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Language-Addison-Wesley-Professional-Computing/dp/0134190440) (but again, I myself haven't read it yet).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you mkopriva as pointed
when you pass `&vehicles` which is `[]entities.Vehicles` to Find the query generated would be as below:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  vehicles
JOIN
  vehicles vh
ON vh.id = vehicle_collisions.vehicle_id
WHERE vehicle_collisions.collision_id=1
```

which won't be correct to solve the problem modify the query as:

```golang
err := r.db.
    Joins("JOIN vehicle_collisions AS vc ON vc.vehicle_id=vehicles.id").
    Where("vc.collision_id = ?", id).
    Find(&vehicles).Error
```

Comment: Hi Chandan, Thank you for your answere but it is again displaying the same error.

Answer (score 0):

As the question lacks some details, I tried to guess them. I hope that the answer provided is relevant to you! Let me present the code that is working on my side:

```golang
package main

import (
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

type Vehicle struct {
    Id         string
    Make       string
    Model      string
    Collisions []Collision `gorm:"many2many:vehicle_collisions"`
}

type Collision struct {
    Id        string
    Longitude float64
    Latitude  float64
}

func main() {
    dsn := "host=localhost user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres port=5432 sslmode=disable"
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    db.AutoMigrate(&Vehicle{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&Collision{})

    // add dummy data to the db
    collision := &Collision{"1", 4.4, 4.5}
    db.Create(collision)
    db.Create(&Collision{"2", 1.1, 1.5})
    db.Create(&Vehicle{Id: "1", Make: "ford", Model: "fiesta", Collisions: []Collision{*collision}})
    db.Create(&Vehicle{Id: "2", Make: "fiat", Model: "punto", Collisions: []Collision{*collision}})

    // get all vehicles for collision 1
    var vehicles []Vehicle
    db.Debug().Joins("inner join vehicle_collisions vc on vehicles.id = vc.vehicle_id").Find(&vehicles, "vc.collision_id = ?", "1")
}
```

The code starts with the structs' definitions.

> Please note the Gorm annotation on the field `Collisions`.

After adding some data, the query should be pretty straightforward: we use the `Joins` method to load data from the table `vehicle_collisions` and in the `Find` method we filter out only records with `collision_id` equal to `"1"`.
Let me know if this helps you or you need something else!

Comment: Hi @Umar Farooq, did you manage it?